# TOR 4.0.2 not working

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, help

I've just downloaded Tor browser version 4.0.2, it connects to the Tor network and the web browser but comes up with this message  Something Went Wrong!

Tor is not working in this browser.

I am running windows 8. Can somebody help me with this problem?

thanks